# Golang + Angular

Tags: angular, go, routes

I started trying to work with Go and Angular, but I have a weird issue.. I guess I'm just missing a tiny detail, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter as a router for Go ... now with Angular, I should be able to copy & paste a URL into the browser and Angular should handle the according routes, right?

I have a "/login" route. Which works if the route gets accessed via the front-end .... but doesn't if I type in "mypage.com/login" into the browser, getting a 404.

Go routing basically is only doing

```
router.NotFound = http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))
```

Which works for the "/" route, but not for anything else. Which seems to be correct. But how do I setup the routing correctly, so Angular handles all the routing?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I got the same question!!

Answer (score 13):

This is what I am using with the standard Go library, and routing works great.

Check out the [Adapt function here](http://go-talks.appspot.com/github.com/matryer/golanguk/building-apis.slide#30)

```
// Creates a new serve mux
mux := http.NewServeMux()

// Create room for static files serving
mux.Handle("/node_modules/", http.StripPrefix("/node_modules", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./node_modules"))))
mux.Handle("/html/", http.StripPrefix("/html", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))))
mux.Handle("/js/", http.StripPrefix("/js", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./js"))))
mux.Handle("/ts/", http.StripPrefix("/ts", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ts"))))
mux.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css"))))

// Do your api stuff**
mux.Handle("/api/register", util.Adapt(api.RegisterHandler(mux),
    api.GetMongoConnection(),
    api.CheckEmptyUserForm(),
    api.EncodeUserJson(),
    api.ExpectBody(),
    api.ExpectPOST(),

))
mux.HandleFunc("/api/login", api.Login)
mux.HandleFunc("/api/authenticate", api.Authenticate)

// Any other request, we should render our SPA's only html file,
// Allowing angular to do the routing on anything else other then the api    
// and the files it needs for itself to work.
// Order here is critical. This html should contain the base tag like
// <base href="/"> *href here should match the HandleFunc path below 
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "html/index.html")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `http` package directly.

#### Index page

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./public/index.html")
})
```

This will serve the index.html file on all requests that don't match a route.

#### File server

```
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))
```

This will serve all files from the public directory.

Don't forget to start your server

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

Comment: same problem, i visit "/login" and get a 404.

Comment: Are you still using httprouter?

Comment: no, i'm not. just plain Go. With your edited solution i'm getting blank pages, so i guess that's one step closer already.

Comment: check your browser console for any javascript errors. Your page might be getting served but angular might not be rendering the page

Comment: yeah, i'm getting "Unexpected token <" on every .js file

Comment: sounds like html files are getting served instead js files.

Comment: yeah, i'm also getting "Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103341/discussion-between-ninja-andrej-and-jmaloney).

Answer (score 1):

use goji micro framwork

https://github.com/zenazn/goji

It's easy to use

```
func render_html_page(w http.ResponseWriter, url string) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(url) 
    if err != nil {
        panic (err)
    }
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func index(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    render_html_page(w, "./public/index.html")
}

func main() {
        goji.Get("/", index)
        goji.Serve()
}
```

this code works, you need just make imports

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact 404 problem. This routing is html5mode. You need to tell handlers in your app.yaml. Check my fork of Tour of Heroes project here https://github.com/nurp/angular2-tour-of-heroes

adding this to your app.yaml might solve the problem.

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define router.Notfound handler to serve angular index.html file.

```
import (
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func angularHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.ServeFile(w, r, "./public/index.html")
}

func main() {
  router := httprouter.New()

  // handle angular
  router.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(angularHandler)

  // serve static files
  router.ServeFiles("/*filepath", http.Dir("./public"))

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router))
}
```